# Fit div container to video size (fullscreen as well)

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video, overlay

I'm trying to get a text overlaying a video and behave accordingly to its resizing.

Currently my trouble is to make the container of the video at the same size as the player (as well as in fullscreen mode).

My container is positioned relatively and both my video and text overlay div are positioned absolutely:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
        <video id="videoPlayer" controls="true"></video>
        <div id="videoCaption"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
position: relative;
}

#videoPlayer{
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}

#videoCaption{
position: absolute;
z-index: 2147483647;
font-size: 80%;
line-height: 125%;
text-align: left;
color: #c9302c;
background-color: #000000;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: "monospaceSansSerif";
}
```

Here a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/xw17xbc9/1/

Container has no height (1904px x 0px), video player is 1280px x 720px and my videoCaption div is 205px x 16px (size that take the text), stuck ar the top-left corner of the player.

Well, basically the result I'd like to achieve is a little bit like the Youtube videos pop-ups overlaying.

Any lead is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: post a working example using jsbin, or codepen.

Comment: Thks, edited and the working example with JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xw17xbc9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand completely what you are trying to do, but [this updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw17xbc9/2/) shows the video container taking the height of the video player.

Parent elements won't take on the height of their children if they are `position:absolute`. I made the video player element `position:relative`, then added `top:0px; left:0px;` to place the text container back in the top left of the container.

**Update**

[New jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw17xbc9/5/) showing container taking both height *and* width of the child video element.

Comment: Thanks for the height fix, it works. However the width is taking the one from the window, not the width of the player.

Comment: @Hetana Oh, just add `display:inline-block` to the container div.

Comment: Thanks, but if you do that, you don't have access to the controls anymore.

Comment: @Hetana Ah, that is because you had `z-index: -1` set on the player (I assume to keep it under the text). I removed that line, and the player controls are now accessible (and the text remains above the video player).

Comment: @Hetana Also, if you're interested in making videos like this without having to go through the trouble of constructing the player yourself, I would take a look at [WIREWAX](http://wirewax.com).

Comment: Currently sick I can't test it, but just to let you know that I'm working with Dash.js and its player.  I'll validate an answer as soon as I'm back on feet and I tested them.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want a full screen video, if i understand correctly.

[Here is the fullscreen demo](http://jsbin.com/witiquxaci/3/) and here it is [the live code](http://jsbin.com/witiquxaci/3/edit?html,css,js,output).

Use the JS to adapt the video: it will depend on its ratio and the window ratio. Below the snippet of code. See the JSBIN to test it:

```
function(){

        wWidth = $(window).width();
        wHeight = $(window).height();

        if (wWidth / s.ratio < wHeight) { // if new video height < window height (gap underneath)
            pWidth = Math.ceil(wHeight * s.ratio); // get new player width
            $(s.playerId).width(pWidth).height(wHeight).css({left: (wWidth - pWidth) / 2, top: 0}); // player width is greater, offset left; reset top
        } else { // new video width < window width (gap to right)
            pHeight = Math.ceil(wWidth / s.ratio); // get new player height
            $(s.playerId).width(wWidth).height(pHeight).css({left: 0, top: (wHeight - pHeight) / 2}); // player height is greater, offset top; reset left
        }
 };
```

Edit your video ratio in the function settings:

```
"ratio"         : 16/9
```

Comment: I was currently more concerned with the container size, but it will surely be a big help later on. Thanks